# JQuery $.get : search the data response to get some attribute value

Tags: jquery, get, replacewith

I'm trying to replace a div with its updated version using $.get. I'm doing something like this :

```
$('.clickable').click( function() { 
   $.get(url, function(data) {
      $(this).replaceWith(data);
   });
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I guess this $(this) doesn't like to be changed that way, or should it work? In case it shouldn't I would like to retrieve the attributes values of the current div by searching the data, is it possible ?

Edit : Removed `$.get(url + ' #' + $(this).attr('id')` because it seems $.get does not behave like load() actually. Hence, the div replaced is going to display the whole data... If anyone has a proper solution to select just a part of the data, I would appreciate. Add a commentary or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.clickable').click( function() { 
   $.get(url + ' #' + $(this).attr('id'), function(data) {
      $(this).replaceWith(data); // here
   });
});
```

In the scope of your callback, `this` refers to the callback itself. Use another variable temporary storing the clickable:

```
$('.clickable').click( function() { 
   var that = this;
   $.get(url + ' #' + $(this).attr('id'), function(data) {
      $(that).replaceWith(data);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In you `$.get` function, there is a new scope, so `this` is not what `this` was before. You could save this in a variable:

```
$('.clickable').click( function() { 
   var elem = this;
   $.get(url + ' #' + $(this).attr('id'), function(data) {
      $(elem).replaceWith(data);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this refers to the get object, you may set it to an identifier before calling the get action 
i.e.

```
$('.clickable').click( function() { 
   var replaceable = this;
   $.get(url + ' #' + $(this).attr('id'), function(data) {
      $(replaceable).replaceWith(data);
   });
});
```